# invalid request illegal request

Tags: python-requests, request

So I'm trying to request data to a url like this . The url is already correct, cookie is correct and I also make sure the params are correct. As far as I know, wrong cookie will result `b'{"errcode":2, "message": "token not found"}'`, wrong url will return empty response url not found / error 404. I think it has something to do with the data that is passed to params. The problem is I already make sure the params is correct but it still returns the error

```
ck2 = "cookie"
request_data2 = {
        "url": 'myurl',
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "cookie": ck2,
            "user-agent": USER_AGENT,
        },
        "data": {
            "SPC_CDS" : "c965e097-8cce-4ac0-b713-1b98567f15e2",
            "SPC_CDS_VER": "2",
            "promotion_id": "748814770451103"
        },
    }
```

Payload on request

[image]

See that it's exactly the same, but still returns `b'{"code":10011,"msg":"err:invalid request, detail:Illegal request"}\n'`